# Generate and get invoice PDF via PHP with WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, invoice

## What I want

I want to generate the PDF-invoices via a PHP-script and store it to a certain location (probably a folder next to the .php file: `"invoices/2020-12-29_invoices.pdf"`). I have an array of the order-ids which I want to have the PDFs from (example: `array('123132','12321',...)`).

## How it is done via Wp-Admin

In the admin panel somebody can create the invoice-PDF with the dropdown "PDF Invoice" in WooCommerce->PDF Invoice and on a button-click following example link is generated for the orders selected:

https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=generate_wpo_wcpdf&document_type=invoice&order_ids=123132x12321&_wpnonce=3fnonce29

The link contains the order-ids of which the PDF should be generated and a _wpnonce. The link itself is a PDF file.

## Why I struggle

Most of it is done via jQuery, ajax and human to operate it manually, but I want to have it automaticly done via php for a list of order-ids.

## What I discovered

Probably `wp_create_nonce('generate_wpo_wcpdf')` can be of use

## Plugins I use

- WooCommerce
- WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips (https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/#description)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a PDF in code, you can do it like this:

```
$invoice = wcpdf_get_document( 'invoice', $order, true );
$pdf_data = $invoice->get_pdf();
```

You can then use the PDF data to save to a file (file_put_contents etc)

If you want to use the admin-ajax link, you can create the nonce like this:

```
wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=generate_wpo_wcpdf&template_type=invoice&order_ids=' . $list_of_order_ids ), 'generate_wpo_wcpdf' )
```

Comment: use `$invoice->output_pdf();` for direct download of invoice